# Best Way to get parameter fom external software

Tags: php

I use a php script to track and manage payments recepits.
In this script i have some fields like:

```
TRANSACTION ID (ERP Reference)
DATE
FURNISHER
INVOICE NUMBER
PAYMENT DATE
AMOUNT
UPLOAD (select dialog to upload a PDF with bank transaction)
```

Now, we have ERP software.
User first add payment on ERP and after submit record user get transaction ID and bank transaction.
After this user scan some documents, FILL FIELDS on script and upload a PDF FILE.

I'm like to send some data from ERP to PHP script, in this way user cannot fill forms twice.

My Idea is create a button on ERP to open a browser window and submit data by URL, like:

```
myscript.com/receive.php?erp_transaction=1223232&date=2016-01-01&furnisher=Microsoft&invoice_number=A1210&payment_date=2016-06-01&amount=100.00
```

QUESTION: IS BEST WAY?

TKS All,

Comment: yes  .. is the simple  http  get method

Comment: Or export to a text file but that is probably not easier.